# Log4Net Appender Not Loading

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Log4Net isn't able to load the appender for the DB2 connection and I cannot see why. It writes the logs to the file system fine, however, the DB2 logging isn't occurring. The version of Log4Net is `v1.2.10.0`.

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="100" />
    <connectionType value="IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection,IBM.Data.DB2, Version=8.1.2.1" />
    <connectionString value="server=db2Server;database=dbName;user Id=userId1;password=password;persist security info=true" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO GOSDDL.EXCEPTION_LOG (APP_LOG_TS,THREAD,LEVEL,LOGGER,MESSAGE,EXCEPTION) VALUES (@log_date,@thread,@log_level,@logger,@message,@exception)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%utcdate" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="../logs" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="512KB"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd.lo" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%d %l %-2p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <levelMin value="INFO"/>
      <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Try to enable internal debugging in log4net and see if you can find anything suspicious. See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html section "How do I enable log4net internal debugging?"

Comment: Thank you Andreas. I did enable this orginally which is how I found out that the appender wasn't being picked up. It just doesn't seem to recognize the appender I am attempting to add. Not sure why though, which is what my problem is. When I only have the DB value logging it states "log4net: Logger: No appenders could be found for logger [System.Exception] repository [log4net-default-repository]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the risk of pointing out the obvious, the config file you posted does not actually use AdoNetAppender. Would this be a matter of replacing RollingFile with AdoNetAppender in the second last line?

If not, can you post the rest of the config file.

Comment: Sometimes a point to the obvious is all we need good sir. Thank you didn't even pay attention to that final node :-|